# Nested set / Tree javascript renderer gem for Rails 3 with drag & drop anywhere out there?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Before I outsource a plugin / gem for Rails 3 on github I wanted to check if there is any solution out there to not reinvent the wheel.

So my gem would render the [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com) HTML and JavaScript for an [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) model and handles drag & drop.

Comment: Maybe something like this https://github.com/codeodor/plupload-rails3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking a lot for something like this. I haven't found anything at all near elegant and simple or customization.

I've played with jsTree in the past. I'm using jquery treeview at the moment, but yea, definitely haven't found any javascript drag-and-drop solution to work with an interactive nested-set. Good luck! Post a link here I'll check it out when you get going. You might want to look into HTML5 Canvas, I'm using that right now to render a very rough tree view. Gotta get drag-and-drop working. *sigh*